# Removing blank lines from a huge file and creating a delimited file using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a text file that [looks like this](https://gist.github.com/powerupcloud/03a57848504b572947948bd4815d9a9a). I am trying to convert it into standard format with `,` for the column separator (which is already present and `\r\n` for the line terminator.

The problem is, current file is kind of like fixed width + comma separated. Each line should have 167 columns separated by commas. The rows in current file form multiple lines with a line terminator at each line. This format is not supported by most of the loading / external table tools. There are also blank lines after each line which I would like to remove.

I have tried sed so far -

```
zcat myfile.txt.gz | sed 's/^\ *$/%%%/g'  | xargs | sed -e 's/%%%/\n/g'  -e 's/\ //g'  > myfile.txt
```

The above did convert the file and everything seemed fine. But I noticed that some of the rows were not properly converted. Example, on some rows I just has 117 columns.

What am I missing in sed? Are there better/faster ways to do this? Please note that the files I am dealing with are about 25 GB each uncompressed and I have more than hundred of them.

[Sample input](https://gist.github.com/powerupcloud/03a57848504b572947948bd4815d9a9a)

[Desired Output](https://gist.github.com/powerupcloud/d5ff7c67fd028fa5ac3b4dfd731c31d9) (first two lines of sample input)

Comment: What is your expected output from that file?

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input **to your question**.

Comment: I have updated the question with sample input and desired output.

Comment: @RKKuppala: how many columns is that per row?

Comment: 167 columns per row, next the original file will have a blank line - it should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually do it this way :

```
zcat myfile.txt.gz | while read line ; do if test "$line" = "" ; then printf "\r\n" ; else printf "$line" ; fi ;done > myfile.txt
```

On sample input I obtain always 168 columns (167 commas). You can run this code to verify the number of commas per line.

```
zcat myfile.txt.gz | while read line ; do if test "$line" = "" ; then printf "\r\n" ; else printf "$line" ; fi ;done  | sed s/[^,]//g  | while read a ; do echo "$a" |  wc -c   ; done
```

Output obtained is slightly different from desired output you shared (I have an additional 0)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this and it solved the issue:

```
zcat  myfile.txt.gz | sed -r 's/[ ]+/vin/g'|tr -d '\n'|tr 'vinvin' '\n'|grep -v '^$' > myfile.txt
```